# Update option (of Make file) in CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, build-process, cmake

I have a big project that uses CMake to create Make file. Sometimes, I add one small project and then have to run the CMake script for whole project (like delete previous, and create newer CMake with this project included). 
I was wondering, whehter there is some option in CMake whereby I can only "update" the Make script (created by CMake) to include newly added project (rather than above option). 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can only do

```
cmake .
```

in directory which contains CMakeCache.txt. This will trigger whole reconfiguration, but save your options.